# java web start jre version check on client site

Tags: java, java-web-start

Based on https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.txt, I have tried both createWebStartLaunchButton(jnlp, minimumVersion) and createWebStartLaunchButtonEx(jnlp, minimumVersion). However, neither of them direct me to the java update site when the jre version on the client's side is lower than the application requires.

My current Code:

```
  <script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
   <script>
         var url = "http:xxxx.com/xxx.jnlp";    
         deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url, '10.0'); or
         deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButtonEx(url, '10.0');
   </script>
```

The Oracle article doesn't seem to offer much insights either: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/createWebStartLaunchButtonFunction.html

Has anyone tried or experienced the same issue? Any comments? Thank you in advance.

Comment: According to the link you gave the code should work `Specifying a minimum version of JRE software that is required to run the application
<script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    var url = "http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/apps/notepad.jnlp";
    deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url, '1.6.0');
</script>`  **What is your code?**

Comment: <script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script> <script > var url = "jnlp location"; deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButtonEx(url, '10.0');</script>  When I launch it, a dialog box pops out telling me having an outdated jre, when I clicks on the "Run with the latest version", it tells me cannot auto update error message.

Comment: What is `'10.0'` signifying?

Comment: Java version. I wrote and compiled the application on 10.0.2 version, so I assume it has to be 10.0 or higher to run it.

Comment: I thought the latest desktop version of Java will still 1.8 something?

Comment: really? When I run java -version on my cmd, it prints 10.0.2...

Comment: Is that because you have JDK installed?

Comment: it says: java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2 +13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2 +13, mixed mode)

Comment: *SE Runtime Environment 18.3* try *18.3*  BTW I am only running Windows8 and the latest version of java is 1.8.0_181

Comment: Thanks, will try it. Do you think this has anything to do with 64 bit and 32 OS? The app was written and jarred in a 64 bit Windows 7 and I'm testing on a 32 bit Vista. BTW, the 32 bit Vista's java version is indeed 1.8.0_181

Comment: well I would try with a lower version and see what happens